# Cannot install Linux on 32bit UEFI System, blank screen after GRUB

Tags: boot, system-installation, grub, uefi, 32bit

I am currently trying to install Linux on an old Laptop because Windows is extremely slow on it.
It has a 32bit OS and only UEFI, no BIOS and no Legacy Option.
I tried both Debian 32bit and Manjaro 32bit, however after i select the Install option on GRUB, i only see a blank screen. I tried setting the "nomodeset" boot option but this didnt change the result.

Unfortunately i dont't know the exact laptop model but it is of the HP Envy series and originally ran Windows 8.
Secure boot is disabled.

I tried to install from two different USB drives and created them with SUSE Studio Imagewriter, but i also created one using rufus.

Does anybody know how i can install one of these distros (or any other linux distro) on such a machine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the good news is that UEFI is not your problem: If GRUB loads, then UEFI boot worked. It's GRUB's job to get loaded by the UEFI loader, and then load the Linux kernel and boot it. so, we can be pretty sure that works. So, as you've already guessed, it might just be that the kernel has problems with the graphics card in your laptop. Can you see, maybe by some blinking of LEDs, whether the USB stick remains in use after the screen goes black? Old laptops have USB2, and especially USB sticks from the same era can be preeeeetty slow.

Comment: Are you able to run the "live" version from the DVD/USB - this will run more slowly than a proper install, but it will allow you to check out whether you like the basic software.

Comment: @JeremyBoden No, i cannot run the live version, i get a blank screen after selecting how i want to install.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I use an USB that has a built-in LED. It blinks if it is being read/written. The LED stops blinking and glows continuosly a few seconds after the screen goes blank.

Comment: @fritschpegler then probably the kernel hangs somewhere and we can't see it because for some reason (might be the same, might not be the same), it doesn't know how to display stuff :(

Comment: Can you try a CD/DVD? You can try an [old version](https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/) and see if it boots. That would also rule out a problem with the USB drive and/or USB bus. In any case, try with another USB drive and, if you have options, try to connect it to another port too. I think it is related to the media, more than to the PC.

Comment: Even the oldest HP Envy should handle 64bit, no?

Comment: Only a few tablet type systems were 32 bit UEFI, but 64 bit chips. Many full 64 bit systems had 32  bit Windows. Those systems often had low RAM, and then you may not want Ubuntu, but a lightweight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie

Comment: Well one of your options is trying different distros/kernels until there's some that works at least, installing it and converting to Debian *userspace* if you prefer that; maybe try if http://en.altlinux.org/rescue boots there (it's a text-based live image) and if it does, have a closer look at http://getalt.org either.